# Object height determination through Split Stereo image visualization QGIS

Tags: photogrammetry

Is there any way to display (Aero-triangulated) left and right images (Stereo photogrammetry) in 2 mapview/viewport(different viewport/Map View/Multiple Canvas) in QGIS. So that we can use Sensor parameter (Azimuth and Elevation angle of different satellite) to calculate Object height By syncing of Left and right image.

Clicking on Point A (Left Image) and same point on Right image will calculate Azimuth from top to bottom of wall for both image is height of Object (Please correct if I am wrong)
Multiplication factor also can be applied
[image]